# JavaFX combobox set PromptText after selection option

Tags: javafx, combobox, prompt

I've set a prompt text for my combobox which appears before selecting an option.

After the user selects an element in the ComboBox I want that text to appear again, but I don't want it to be a ComboBox item.

I tried clearing the selection and setting the prompt text again, but no text is appearing, it's empty.

How do I need to do it?

Comment: Can you post minimal, reproductive example of your code?

Comment: As far as I'm aware (and according to other answers here), this is not possible. There's no way to get the prompt text back.

Comment: don't understand _after the user selects an element in the ComboBox I want that text to appear again_ - how would you show both the selectedItem and the promptText? Anyway, [mcve] please, as already suggested by @Tom

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc states:

> public final void setPromptText(String value)
>
> Sets the value of the property promptText.
>
> Property description:
>
> The ComboBox prompt text to display, or null if no prompt text is displayed. Prompt text is not displayed in all circumstances, it is dependent upon the subclasses of ComboBoxBase to clarify when promptText will be shown. For example, in most cases prompt text will never be shown when a combo box is non-editable (that is, prompt text is only shown when user input is allowed via text input).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#setPromptText-java.lang.String-